# Order by some specific column value

Tags: angularjs

When I have an `ng-repeat`, is it possible to show some specific values first?

```
<tr ng-repeat="process in processesArray |orderBy: process.userName='ADMIN':reverse ">
```

Basically, I want to show processes from ADMIN at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom `orderBy` function and if the text is Admin return a value that will place it at the bottom of the list:

```
$scope.adminLast = function(item) {
    if (item.userName == "ADMIN")
        return 0;
    else 
        return 1;
}

ng-repeat="process in processesArray |orderBy: adminLast"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I never saw that on any example and that work.